# Understanding of functions in GMP library

Tags: c++, gmp

I have a question, how to call functions from GMP lib. C++. For example I want to check whether a number is prime by calling the function `mpz_probab_prime_p (mpz_t A, int B)` , docs says it should return 0 when ithe number is composite and 1 or 2 when it's not. But it only returns 0.

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int iter;
cout<<"How many numbers do you want to get? ";
cin>>iter;

mpz_t q;
mpz_init (q);
cout<<"Choose starting number q = ";
scanf("%Zx\n",q);

printf("%u",mpz_probab_prime_p(q,iter));

return 0;}
```

I can code basic algorithms, but never actually used special libraries before.

Comment: That’s not how you’d read a multi-precision integer from stdin. Actually it’s a little impressive that the program doesn’t crash.

Comment: I think you want to reread https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Input